# How to update request headers in MV3 extension like we used to do in MV2 (chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I'm in the process of transitioning my MV2 extension to MV3. However, I've encountered an issue with conditional header modifications in the chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders event. I've already updated my manifest file and added the necessary permissions. Can you provide guidance or a solution specifically for this header modification challenge during the MV3 migration?

```
window.chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(params) {
        'use strict';
        var headers = params.requestHeaders,
            url = params.url;
        if (Tabs.indexOf(parms.tabId) > -1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                var currentUserAgent = edit.userAgent; 
                var currentHeader = headers[i];
                // Headers are only sent in case of device modes
                if (currentHeader.name.toLowerCase() === 'user-agent'){
                    currentHeader.value = currentUserAgent;
                }
                if (edit.device === 'android-phone') {
                    if (currentHeader.name.toLowerCase() === 'sec-ch-ua') {
                        currentHeader.value = '"Google Chrome";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"';
                    } else if (currentHeader.name.toLowerCase() === 'sec-ch-ua-mobile') {
                        currentHeader.value = '?1';
                    } else if (currentHeader.name.toLowerCase() === 'sec-ch-ua-platform') {
                        currentHeader.value = '"Android"';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            requestHeaders: headers
        };
    },

    {
        urls: [
            '<all_urls>'
        ]
    }, ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
);
```

I'm working on migrating my extension from Manifest V2 to Manifest V3, and I'm facing an issue with the following code not functioning in MV3. I'm aware of the **`chrome.declarativeNetRequest`** API, but I'm struggling to understand how to adapt this code to work with it. Can someone provide guidance or an explanation on how to achieve the same functionality using **`chrome.declarativeNetRequest`** in MV3?

Comment: You need to remove this code and write rules using chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules every time when `edit.userAgent` is changed.

Comment: so how can i like write conditionally as like when edit.device === 'android-phone' could you please tell me

Comment: There'll be no listener. When the value is changed you'll remove the old rule and add a new one with the new headers as shown in examples for chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules.